# Azure website error Your connection is not private

Tags: azure, dns, web, azure-web-roles, azure-web-app-service

I'm trying to set up a domain name in azure. https://pp.vk.me/c623722/v623722762/180cb/SwBEjiWmCGY.jpg

I changed different settings, but that did not work.

I get an error:

http://booveron.com

What could be the problem?

Thanks

Comment: This question might be considered off topic, I have proposed a better site to ask such questions, follow if you agree. http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/82757/cloud-computing-platforms

Answer (score 2):

You haven't uploaded a custom SSL certificate to go along with your website instance, hence the Website server hosting your site with a custom domain is simply serving up the *.azurewebsites.net SSL certificate that is deployed by default.